# Неправильные координаты изображения (Swing)

Tags: java, swing

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, почему изображение не рисуется в нужных координатах? В `MainClass` создается обьект `ImageResizer`, a `ImageResizer` рисует картинку (со стрелками, но это не по теме) с заданными из `MainClass` параметрами. В этом случае изображение рисуется в `(120,6)` (или `(120,36)` учитывая панель окна), но на самом деле оно рисуется в `(250,6)`.

ImageResizer:

```
public class ImageResizer extends JComponent {
    private int x, y, width, heigth;
    private Image img;
    ImageResizer(int x, int y, int width, int heigth, Image img){
        super.setBounds(x,y,width,heigth);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.heigth = heigth;
        this.img = img;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D gr = (Graphics2D)g;

        gr.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        gr.drawImage(img, x, y, width, heigth, null);

        try {
            ((Graphics2D) g).drawImage(ImageIO.read(new File("arrowAboveLeft.png")),x,y,20,20,null);
            ((Graphics2D) g).drawImage(ImageIO.read(new File("arrowAboveRight.png")),width-20,y,20,20,null);
            ((Graphics2D) g).drawImage(ImageIO.read(new File("arrowBelowLeft.png")),x,heigth-20,20,20,null);
            ((Graphics2D) g).drawImage(ImageIO.read(new File("arrowBelowRight.png")),width-20,heigth-20,20,20,null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    public int getHeigth() {
        return heigth;
    }
}
```

MainClass:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("digital.jpg"));
        ImageResizer ir = new ImageResizer(120, 6, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), img);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(null);

        panel.add(ir);
        frame.setBounds(200, 200, 400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                int x = ir.getX();
                int y = ir.getY();
                int width = ir.getWidth();
                int heigth = ir.getHeight();
                int eX = e.getX();
                int eY = e.getY();
                if ((eX >= x))//&& (eX <=x+width) && e.getY()>=y+30 && e.getY()<=y+heigth+30)
                    System.out.println("Here: " + eX + ", " + eY);
            }
        });
    }}
```

Comment: предположу, что `setBounds` в `ImageResizer` задает  координаты компонента в системе контейнера (на 120 правее левой стороны фрейма), а `paintComponent` рисует относительно левой стороны `ImageResizer`, т.е. вы дважды отступаете на 120.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Да, дело было в этом. Исправил.